# How to kill all processes from a certain users across multiple machines?

Tags: bash, ssh, remote-access, kill

Given a list of users machines in a file `hosts.txt`:

```
# Group 1
user1@192.68.0.1
user2@192.68.0.2
user1@192.68.0.3

# Group 2
user1@192.68.1.111
user3@192.68.1.222
```

**Is there a way to automatically kill the processes for these users on the respective machines?**

Currently, I'm doing these commands one-by-one manually:

```
ssh user1@192.68.0.1
sudo killall -u user1

ssh user2@192.68.0.2
sudo killall -u user2

ssh user1@192.68.0.3
sudo killall -u user1

ssh user1@192.68.1.111
sudo killall -u user1

ssh user3@192.68.1.222
sudo killall -u user3
```

Comment: `sshpass -p<passwd> ssh user1@192.68.0.1 'sudo killall -u user1'` ? You can use `sshpass` as shown to automatically handle the password prompt, if you don't have password-less ssh setup to remote machines.

Comment: You can run commands on the remote machine directly e.g. `ssh user1@192.68.0.1 "sudo killall -u user1"`

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like that:

```
for i in $(seq 1 5); do echo ssh user$i@192.168.0.$i "sudo pkill -u user$i"; done
```

Just lose the `echo` (it's for testing purposes) and edit the second number of the `seq` command to match the number you want.

Example:

```
itai@Itais-MacBook-Pro ~ -  $ for i in $(seq 1 5); do echo ssh user$i@192.168.0.$i "sudo pkill -u user$i"; done
ssh user1@192.168.0.1 pkill -u user1
ssh user2@192.168.0.2 pkill -u user2
ssh user3@192.168.0.3 pkill -u user3
ssh user4@192.168.0.4 pkill -u user4
ssh user5@192.168.0.5 pkill -u user5
itai@Itais-MacBook-Pro ~ -  $
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

# list all the remote users here in the format "<user>/<passwd>@<ip>"
users=(
'user1/pwd1@192.68.0.1'
'user2/@192.68.0.2'  # password-less ssh is setup to this user
# user3 etc...
)

for i in ${users[@]}; do
    if ! [[ $i =~ (.+)/(.*)@(.+)$ ]]; then
        echo "unable to parse entry $i"
        exit -1
    fi
    user="${BASH_REMATCH[1]}"
    pass="${BASH_REMATCH[2]}"
    ip="${BASH_REMATCH[3]}"
    if [[ -z $pass ]]; then
        ssh $user@$ip "sudo killall -u $user"
    else
        sshpass -p $pass ssh $user@$ip "sudo killall -u $user"
    fi
done
```

If you have already setup password-less ssh accessibility to a certain machine, then you can keep the password section empty for that specific machine (see the example above).

Note that you may have to install `sshpass` first, as normally it is not installed by default.